# Retrieve values seperated by comma's in QGIS column

Tags: qgis, string

What is the simplest way to retrieve each value to a new column from a string with values separated by commas in QGIS?

My data look kind of like this:

```
STRING
-----------
wp1,wp2,wp3
```

but I want

```
STRING1 | STRING2 | STRING3
--------|---------|--------
 wp1    | wp2     | wp3
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Create three new fields with field calculator and this expression: `string_to_array(string)[0]` for string 1 and replace `[0]` with `[1]` for string 2 etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "Vector table > Refactor fields" tool.

In the tool window:

- Add three new fields.
- Populate the text boxes as in the image:
  Expression: `string_to_array(string)[0]`

[image]

Result:

[image]